# Re-signing ipa with expired provisioning profile and with a valid certificate

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa, codesign

I got an ipa and I re-signed it with expired provisioning profile (Enterprise) and with a valid certificate(.p12). using steps mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619389/re-signing-ipa-with-new-provisioning-profile-and-with-new-certificate-ipad)!

when I am extracting ipa (getting .App file) -> doing show package Contents (on .App) -> checking content of embedded.mobileprovision. it show same expired provisioning profile that i used to Re-sign the ipa.

Problem : I am successfully able to install it to ipad and able to run the app.
Ideally App should not work with Expired provisioning profile.

Question : If we Re-signing the app through Command-line with Expired profile Will it work.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Question was "If we Re-signing the app through Command-line with Expired profile Will it work.?"

Answer is no.

It can work in the device only in one case. If your device already have a valid provisioning profile for the same app.

So its better to remove valid provisioning profile from your device. connect device to your computer "xcode-> windows-> Devices-> select your device(at left hand side)-> click on setting icon located on bottom left-> click on show installed provisioning profiles then select profile and delete it -> done" then test. App will not work if it is created with Expired provisioning profile.

Comment: You are correct.  The embedded provisioning profile in the .app can be expired if the device already has a valid provisioning profile that supports the bundle id of the app.  So if you have a provisioning profile that supports the wildcard bundle id that was installed by another app that has the new, valid provisioning profile, you can still install the old app that has the expired provisioning profile.